# Connecting VM to wireless adapter on MacBook Pro

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, vmware-fusion

I have VMWare Fusion running on Mac OS X (Leopard). I have a Windows XP Pro virtual machine configured with bridged networking.

This works fine if my laptop is connected to a wired network connection but not if I'm on a wireless connection. When I'm on the wireless connection it cannot get an IP address.

Any thoughts or hints on how to get this working?

Comment: About two hours after I posted this question, my MacBook Pro succumbed to a known issue with the nvidia video chip and is now out for a logic board replacement. I'll test your suggestions next week after I get the machine back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your VM running in windowed mode (not Unity or full-screen), at the lower-right corner of the window, there are a series of icons for the various pieces of virtual hardware that can be linked to the VM.  The networking icon looks like this: <...> (it's the same icon OS X uses for networking).

There's a screenshot of the icons I'm describing here:

[image: VMWare Fusion Screenshot]

Note that these are on the VMWare Fusion status bar, *not* the Windows task bar in the VM window.

You can click on the networking icon and connect your various networking devices to the VM.  It sounds like your Wifi connection is not being linked, so look for the Wireless connection in the menu that comes on and click on it.  In a few seconds, your VM should be sharing your Mac's wireless connection!

Answer (score 0):

vmware has different networking cards for the different physical cards in your computer. For example, vmnet1 is mapped to your eth0, you will need to map 'vmnet2' to your wlan0, you should be able to do that from the vmware software. You may have to go as far as to reinstall/re configure your vmware install. I have to do it for my vmware server installs at least.